# White screen on Samsung i9105p

Tags: screen, boot, samsung-galaxy-s-2-plus

The other day I sideloaded an application and my screen froze, then turned white.  After I restarted my device, it just showed white lines on a black screen.  Sometimes it turns white, sometimes it has lines (rarely).

How can I fix this?

[image]